# How can I efficiently bin 3D point cloud data based on point coordinates and desired bin grid size

Tags: python, numpy, point-clouds, open3d

I have a large point cloud in open3D and I want to basically make a 3D grid and bin the points based on which cube they are in. Other have called it "binning in 3D space."

[Example image with grids only in one direction (I want to split into 3D volumes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si40Q.png)

[Better Image of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVHcW.png)

Example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[ 0, -1, 10],
 [ 1, -2 ,11],
 [ 2, -3 ,12],
 [ 3, -4 ,13],
 [ 4, -5 ,14],
 [ 5, -6 ,15],
 [ 6, -7 ,16],
 [ 7, -8 ,17],
 [ 8, -9 ,18]])

#point 1: X,Y,Z
#point 2: X,Y,Z

print(A)

X_segments = np.linspace(0,8,3) #plane at beginning, middle and end - this creates 2 sections where data can be
Y_segments = np.linspace(-9,-1,3)
Z_segments = np.linspace(10,18,3)

#all of these combined form 4 cuboids where data can be 
#its also possible for the data to be outside these cuboids but we can ignore that

bin1 =  A where A[0,:] is > X_segments [0] and < X_segments[1]
    and A where A[1,:] is > Y_segments [0] and < Y_segments[1] 
    and A where A[2,:] is > Z_segments [0] and < Z_segments[1] 

bin2 =  A where A[0,:] is > X_segments [1] and < X_segments[2]
    and A where A[1,:] is > Y_segments [0] and < Y_segments[1] 
    and A where A[2,:] is > Z_segments [0] and < Z_segments[1] 

bin3 =  A where A[0,:] is > X_segments [1] and < X_segments[2]
    and A where A[1,:] is > Y_segments [1] and < Y_segments[2] 
    and A where A[2,:] is > Z_segments [0] and < Z_segments[1] 

bin4 =  A where A[0,:] is > X_segments [1] and < X_segments[2]
    and A where A[1,:] is > Y_segments [1] and < Y_segments[2] 
    and A where A[2,:] is > Z_segments [1] and < Z_segments[2]
```

Thanks yall!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[ 0, -1, 10],
              [ 1, -2 ,11],
              [ 2, -3 ,12],
              [ 3, -4 ,13],
              [ 4, -5 ,14],
              [ 5, -6 ,15],
              [ 6, -7 ,16],
              [ 7, -8 ,17],
              [ 8, -9 ,18]])

X_segments = np.linspace(0,8,3)
Y_segments = np.linspace(-9,-1,3)
Z_segments = np.linspace(10,18,3)

edges = [X_segments, Y_segments, Z_segments]

print(edges) # just to show edges of the bins
```

We get:

```
[[ 0.  4.  8.]
 [-9. -5. -1.]
 [10. 14. 18.]]
```

Next, apply `np.digitize` along each coordinate axis:

```
coords = np.vstack([np.digitize(A.T[i], b, right=True) for i, b in enumerate(edges)]).T
print(coords)
```

This gives:

```
[[0 2 0]
 [1 2 1]
 [1 2 1]
 [1 2 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [2 1 2]
 [2 1 2]
 [2 1 2]
 [2 0 2]]
```

Rows of this array describe positions of the corresponding rows of `A` in the grid of bins. For example, the second row `[1, 2, 1]` indicates that the second row of `A`, i.e. `[1, -2, 11]` is in the first bin along the X-axis (since `0 < 1 <= 4`), in the second bin along the Y-axis (since `-5 < -2 <= -1`), and in the first bin along the Z-axis (since `10 < 11 <= 14`). Then you can pick elements belonging to each cuboid:

```
# select rows of A that are in the cuboid with coordinates [1, 2, 1]
A[np.all(coords == [1, 2, 1], axis=1)]
```

This gives:

```
array([[ 1, -2, 11],
       [ 2, -3, 12],
       [ 3, -4, 13]])
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks!